# How to bind a property from a control inside a ControlTemplate to a property of the parent ContentView?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, maui

I have created a custom control, which can have different presentations. I use ContentView and ControlTemplate for that.

Now the ContentView does have some bindable properties, and it does not bound to a ViewModel.

Check the following pieces of code respectively from the XAML and code-behind of my ContentView:

```
<ContentView.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CarouselTemplate">
        <Label x:Name="myLabel"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentView.Resources>

public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Title), typeof(string), typeof(SelectValueContentView));
public string Title
{
    get => (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
    set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
}
```

**Can you tell me how "myLabel1" can be bound to the Title property ?**

On a side note, I know if it was in the ContentView Content it would be bound with the following syntax:

```
Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference selectValueContentView}, Path=Title}"
```

I also know that if the ContentView was bound to a ViewModel (because its parent page is), the following syntax would work:

```
"{TemplateBinding Path=BindingContext.Title}"
```

So I know that my issue would be quickly solved if I created a ViewModel to "attach" to my ContentView. But I'm not sure it is a good practice, or is it ? I have looked for opinions on this but did not find anything conclusive, please let me know if my current approach is cohesive or not I'm really trying to learn MAUI and XAML.

Many thanks for your help

EDIT: Here is how I consume the ContentView in question. This is a simplified code snippet but you have the idea I think.

```
<ContentPage>
    <views:SelectValueContentView x:Name="selectValueContentView" Title="Some title" Kind="Carousel"/>
</ContentPage>
```

EDIT2:

Here is the code of the SelectValueContentView. As you can see the ControlTemplate is to be applied from the ContentView, and not the ContentPage.

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="IntervalTimerApp.Views.SelectValueContentView"
             x:Name="selectValueContentView"
             >


    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="CarouselTemplate">
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label x:Name="myLabel" Text="{TemplateBinding Path=Title}"/> <!-- This syntax does not work-->
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.Resources>

    <ContentView.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="ContentView" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference selectValueContentView}, Path=Kind}" Value="{x:Static views:SelectValueControlType.Carousel}">
            <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CarouselTemplate}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="ContentView" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference selectValueContentView}, Path=Kind}" Value="{x:Static views:SelectValueControlType.List}">
            <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ListTemplate}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ContentView.Triggers>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: You want to use Binding in a ```ControlTemplate```. So, why not use a TemplateBinding? Or is there anything else you want to achieve? I think ```TemplateBinding``` is the most reasonable way.

Comment: I was not totally sure it was. However I haven’t been able to figure out the correct syntax to bind to the parent ContentView property as described in the issue.

Comment: Could you please show more code about how you consume the ```ControlTemplate```?

Comment: Sure I have just edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use [TemplateBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate?view=net-maui-8.0#pass-parameters-with-templatebinding).

> The TemplateBinding markup extension binds a property of an element that is in a ControlTemplate to a public property that is defined by the templated custom control or templated page.

Let's make an easy demo,

First, you should define the `ControlTemplate` for your custom control in ContentPage Resources and consume it through ControlTemplate Property of `SelectValueContentView`.

Then just set `Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"` to bind the Label's Text Property to the ContentView's Title Property. Please refer to the  code snippet below.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CarouselTemplate">
        <Label x:Name="myLabel" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>


<ContentPage>
    ...
    <views:SelectValueContentView x:Name="selectValueContentView" 
    Title="Some title" Kind="Carousel"
    ControlTemplate="{StaticResource CarouselTemplate}"/>
</ContentPage>
```

---

New Update here

Try this,

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             ...
             x:Name="selectValueContentView"
             ControlTemplate="{StaticResource CarouselTemplate}" >
    
    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="CarouselTemplate">
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>
        ...
    </ContentView.Resources>
    <ContentView.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="ContentView" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference selectValueContentView}, Path=Kind}" Value="Carousel">
            <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CarouselTemplate}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="ContentView" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference selectValueContentView}, Path=Kind}" Value="List">
            <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ListTemplate}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ContentView.Triggers>
</ContentView>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh it was that simple things can get twisted sometimes after a long day of coding lol thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Actually the code snippet you provided does not exactly correspond to the way I am using the ContentView, indeed the ControlTemplate resource is defined in the scope of the ContentView and the page that consumes the ContentView does not know anything about it. I have added a second edit to my question with the code of the ContentView. Do you know what syntax is required in this scenario ? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Why do you put the ControlTemplate in the ContentView? Is there another child ContentView  which consume the ControlTemplate?

Comment: I put the ControlTemplate in the ContentView because I want the latter to offer a different type of UI depending on the value of the "Kind" property, which is to be set by the parent page like so:
<SelectValueContentView Kind="Carousel"/>
I do this because this ContentView is to be used on several pages of my apps, so ideally I would like to keep as much code as possible inside the ContentView class not have the consuming pages caring about much other than providing values for public properties such as Kind or Title. Does that design make sense to you ?

Comment: Okay, now I understand why you do this. Thanks for your explanation.  I have updated my answer.